# Java Keystore: Command "openssl" not found

Tags: java, openssl, keystore

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit and I'm trying to export the base64 encoded sha-hash of my Key with this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias [alias] -keystore [keystore]
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64
```

Unfortunatly I get the error

```
command "openssl" not found
```

I also tried to use other commands, that were shown on this website: http://www.startux.de/index.php/java/44-dealing-with-java-keystores
But I always get the error, that openssl cannot be found. What am I missing?

**Solution**

I was missing openssl. And I downloaded it here: [deanlee.cn/programming/openssl-for-windows](http://deanlee.cn/programming/openssl-for-windows)

Comment: Have you got openssl installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me on Windows, so the only conclusion I can draw is that you are missing openssl, or it is not on your PATH. Either add it, or use the full path to the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Is this on Windows or Linux? These looks like a typical Linux command line and I am pretty sure openssl comes by default on most systems. On windows you may need to look at alternative commands to run or install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Thanks: I was missing openssl. And I downloaded it here: http://www.deanlee.cn/programming/openssl-for-windows/

Comment: Well, I feel slightly bad since I didn't think openssl worked natively under windows so the Cygwin part of my answer is way overkill. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem,what i did download the open ssl http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip&can=2&q=  and  add to windows env PATH variable